# Return index[0] value for a given line in CSV using Python

Tags: python

I can use `with open` in Python to iterate through a Comma Sep text file but I wish to add another level of complexity.
I need to return the value at `index[0]` of a row where a string is found.

For example, I have a text file containing:

```
00:00,19.90,990.49,59.16,11.78,No
01:00,19.92.991.00,59.75,11.90,Yes
02:00,19.76,991.21,58.87,10.95,No
03:00,19.34,989.97,57.00,10.64,Yes
```

now I use:

```
MaxTemp = -float('inf')
MinTemp = +float('inf')
with open (YdPath + yFileDate + '.txt', 'r') as DailyData:
    for lines in DailyData:
        temp = float(lines.strip().split(',')[1])
        if MaxTemp < temp:
            MaxTemp = temp
        if MinTemp > temp:
            MinTemp = temp
```

and output would be:

```
MaxTemp = 19.92
MinTemp = 19.34
```

now though I wish to get the `index[0]` value that relates to these entries, i.e.

MaxTemp needs to find that the entry 19.92 in in the row starting with `index[0]` of 01:00 & be displayed as such, using variable `tTime` as `index[0]` value:

```
print 'The Max Temp was ' + MaxTemp + ' recorded at ' +  tTime
```

Thanks for looking

**UPDATE**

thanks goes to [Henry Heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5341275/henry-heath) for the help & pointers.

Needed 2 time variables as the `MaxTemp` & `MinTemp` were returning the exact same time using `tTime` here is the correct working code:

```
MaxTemp = -float('inf')
MinTemp = +float('inf')

with open (YdPath + yFileDate + '.txt', 'r') as DailyData:
    for line in DailyData:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        temp = float(line[1])
        if MaxTemp < temp:
            MaxTemp = temp
            MXtTime = line[0]
        if MinTemp > temp:
            MinTemp = temp
            MNtTime = line[0]

MaxTemps = '%.1f' %MaxTemp
MinTemps = '%.1f' %MinTemp

print('The Max Temp was ' + MaxTemps + ' recorded at ' + MXtTime)
print('The Min Temp was ' + MinTemps + ' recorded at ' + MNtTime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easier if you use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library

```
MaxTemp = -float('inf')
MinTemp = +float('inf')
with open (YdPath + yFileDate + '.txt', 'r') as DailyData:
    for line in DailyData:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        temp = float(line[1])
        if MaxTemp < temp:
            MaxTemp = temp
            tTime = line[0]
        if MinTemp > temp:
            MinTemp = temp
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked aside from a small issue where the time for both the `MaxTemp` & `MinTemp` was showing as the same but it set me on the correct path. I have added an update to my post reflecting this, although checking your answer as correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @henry-heath ’s suggestion:

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

# n.b., this implementation uses a sort for the brevity of 
# implementation.  However, the original iterative approach 
# will be much faster (O(n) compared to O(n log n)) than
# the version below
with open (YdPath + yFileDate + '.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = [line for line in reader]
    lines.sort(key=lambda x: Decimal(x[1]))
    print 'The Max Temp was ' + lines[-1][1] + ' recorded at ' +  lines[-1][0]
    print 'The Min Temp was ' + lines[0][1] + ' recorded at ' + lines[0][0]
```

Iterative version:

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

with open (YdPath + yFileDate + '.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    line = reader.next()
    line[1] = Decimal(line[1])
    min_temp, max_temp = line, line
    for x in reader:
        x[1] = Decimal(x[1])
        if x[1] < min_temp[1]: min_temp = x
        if x[1] > max_temp[1]: max_temp = x       
    print 'The Max Temp was ' + max_temp[1] + ' recorded at ' +  max_temp[0]
    print 'The Min Temp was ' + min_temp[1] + ' recorded at ' + min_temp[0]
```

Comment: This approach looks promising and easier to read, I'll try it out, thanks.